# AngularJs ng-Repeat Filter stop working on search with "!"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

AngularJS Filter of ng_repeat Doesn't work while searching with text "!".
like searching text is "!icon". then it return result that don't contain "icon".
i have also tried on angularjs.org.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

when i search "28" then it populates only two results but when i search "!28" then it return 8 result that dont contain 28.

Is there any way to considered "!" as a normal character.

Answer (score 0):

The filter in `ng-repeat` behaves exactly as specified in [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

> The string is used for matching against the contents of the array. All strings or objects with string properties in array that match this string will be returned. This also applies to nested object properties. The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with !

You can find the angular comparison code [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/filter.js#L196). I believe there is no simple workaround - it's not a regexp, the code only checks whether `!` is the first character. Even a custom comparator won't work cause the `!` will still do a negation.

The easiest workaround is to create your own $filter for filtering and stop using the `filter` filter.

Comment: Is there any way to considered "!" as a normal character.

Comment: @hitesh Didn't find one and there is no one documented.