# Angularjs: Search filter not working when name starting with ! (exclamation mark)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, filter

I have list of states and I have added search filter on name of states.
I have array like this:

`stateList : [{name: 'abc', area:500},{name: '!def', area:500}]`

I have `<li>` with `ng-repeat="state in stateList | filter:{name:searchText}"`

Search text box with `ng-model="searchText"`

Search is working in normal scenario but when I search !(exclamation mark). It is not giving any result. It should give state with name '!def'

Comment: I suggest you to create your own custom filter

Comment: Any limitation or issue with angularjs search filter?

Comment: It seems AngularJs do a negation with !. take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29048673/angularjs-ng-repeat-filter-stop-working-on-search-with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `!` token is recognized by AngularJS as *"negative predicate"*. Nevertheless you can create your custom `myFilter` like this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.stateList = [{
    name: 'abc',
    area: 500
  }, {
    name: '!def',
    area: 500
  }]
}).filter('myFilter', function() {
  return function(input, filter) {
    if (!filter.name)
      return input;
    return input.filter(function(x) {
      return x.name.indexOf(filter.name) != -1;
    });
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='searchText' />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='state in stateList | myFilter : {name:searchText}'>{{state | json}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
<input type="text" ng-model="state.name"/>

ng-repeat="state in stateList | filter:state"
```

Comment: I want to add filter on name property of state only. So I have to define `filter:{name:searchText}`.

Comment: Sorry. But didnt get your answer. Textbox is for search. right? Why did you write `state.name` in search textbox?