# Angularjs search with exclamation as first letter

Tags: angularjs, filter

Angularjs: Search filter not working when search starting with ! (exclamation mark)

If my data is like name='Anand!'

client side filter should work with searchWord='!'

Please if anyone has solution for the same then provide me the same.

Thanks in advance !!

My Code:

```
<input type="search" class="form-control" ng-model="searchtext" 
placeholder="search here..." />

<div ng-repeat="cust in customers |orderBy:'id' | filter:searchtext">
</div>

$scope.customers = [{
        "id": 1,
        "first_name": "Anand!",
        "last_name": "GK",
        "gender": "Male"           
    }, {
        "id": 2,
        "first_name": "ABC !",
        "last_name": "XYZ",
        "gender": "Female"
    }];
```

Comment: post your code if you want help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs: Search filter not working when name starting with ! (exclamation mark)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587719/angularjs-search-filter-not-working-when-name-starting-with-exclamation-mark)

Comment: Now sample code is there.

Comment: Create custom filter

Comment: we need some global solution like directive.

Comment: @AnandGaikwad what's wrong with filters? [They are working](https://plnkr.co/edit/jywycqQ20JI4Lz3FyGPG?p=preview) just fine

Comment: @Aleksey Solovey  try to search with multiple '!' on this link https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_filters_input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In above example you provide the filter on first_name only and also the function will be common for all so we can use it any where

this can be achieved too, all you have to do is get values of all fields in your `object` and then match the `searchText` like following:-

All you need to do, is write a `custom filter` of your own

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
$scope.customers = [{
    "id": 1,
    "first_name": "Anand!",
    "last_name": "GK",
    "gender": "Male"           
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "first_name": "ABC !",
    "last_name": "XYZ",
    "gender": "Female"
}];
}).filter('searchFilter', function() { /* this the Custom Filter, you can code it to include other fields in search too */
  return function(input, searchText) {
    if (!searchText)
      return input;
    var matchedRecord = [];
    var matchFound = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
       for (var key in input[i]) {
          if(input[i][key] != undefined && input[i][key].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
             matchFound = true;
          }
       }
       if(matchFound)
          matchedRecord.push(input[i]);
       matchFound = false;
    }
    return matchedRecord;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <input type='text' ng-model='searchText' />
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat='customer in customers | searchFilter: searchText'>{{customer | json}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, but we want to filter on whole data not on particular field.                                                                                    In above example you provide the filter on first_name only and also the function will be common for all so we can use it any where.

Comment: @AnandGaikwad edited the answer, its generic `filter` now.

Comment: Only one change need to be there: add check for field value if not null or undefined before converting to string.